# Сравнение двух текстовых файлов с последующим выведением совпадений (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сравнение, txt

Приветствую сообщество stackoverflow. Есть два текстовых файла ('file.txt', 'file2.txt'), нужно провести сравнение и вывести совпадение. Я тут набросал работающий вариант, и мне в нем нравиться, что вывод игнорирует если строка в одном из файлов начинается с пробела или какой-либо вступительной фразы - выводит только совпадения. Однако есть и недостаток указал их #так.

```
        with open(file.txt) as file1:  
            for line in file1:  
                filelist1 = line.split()  
                with open(file2.txt) as file2:  
                    for line in file2:
                        filelist2 = line.split()  
                            resoult = list(set(filelist1) & set(filelist2))  
                            if resoult == []:  #(осторожно наколхозил) вот тут мне не нравиться, если не использовать эту команду при выводе совпадений из текстовых файлов будет множество пустых списков'''
                                continue  
                            else:
                                print(resoult, end='\n')
```

Хотелось бы сюда вставить что-то вроде if/else в плане: если вывод пустой - написать пользователю, что совпадения не найдены; если же 'len(resoult) > 0' - поздравить с найденными совпадениями. Но сделать это с помощью данного кода не представляется возможности.

Пример.

file.txt:

```
груша
яблоко апельсин 
арбуз и дыня
```

file2.txt:

```
манго малина яблоко 
 дыня
```

Мой вывод:

```
['яблоко']
['дыня']
```

Желаемый вывод:

```
Ваши найденные совпадения: 
яблоко
дыня
```

Очень хотелось бы посмотреть, как с этой простой задачей справиться более лаконично и правильно. Заранее прошу прощения за глупость и большое спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: в цикле открывать и по-новой перечитывать второй файл - излишне.

Comment: Вы про ''with open(file2.txt) as file2:'' в цикле  "with open(file.txt) as file1"? Если вынести его в отдельный цикл -  ''resoult = list(set(filelist1) & set(filelist2))" не сможет исполниться должным образом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код не сильно красивый, но вот наипростейший способ найти пересечение множеств:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
lines1 = set(f.read().split())
f.close()
f = open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
lines2 = set(f.read().split())
f.close()

print(lines1)
print(lines2)

print(lines1.intersection(lines2))
```

Вывод:

```
{'груша', 'арбуз', 'апельсин', 'и', 'яблока', 'дыня'}
{'дыня', 'манго', 'яблоко', 'малина'}
{'дыня'}
```

Заметим, что из представленного набора данных слова "яблока" и "яблоко" - разные, поэтому не вывелись.
Чтобы сделать возможным вывод сообщений "найдены" или "не найдены" совпадения, то добавим простую проверку:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
lines1 = set(f.read().split())
f.close()
f = open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
lines2 = set(f.read().split())
f.close()

print('Первое множество:', lines1)
print('Второе множество:', lines2)

intersection = lines1.intersection(lines2)

if len(intersection) > 0:
    print('Совпадения найдены:', intersection)
else:
    print('Совпадения не найдены')
```

Вывод:

```
Первое множество: {'груша', 'яблока', 'арбуз', 'дыня', 'апельсин', 'и'}
Второе множество: {'малина', 'яблоко', 'манго', 'дыня'}
Совпадения найдены: {'дыня'}
```

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос (vinter_man) ''Желаемый вывод..." дополнение к ответу (Sergey K.)

```
if len(intersection) > 0:
    print('Поздравляю с совпадениями:')
else:
    print('Cовпадения не найдены')
for resoults in intersrctoin:
    print('{0:}'.format(resoults))
```

Comment: это ответ на вопрос или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: дополнение к ответу (Sergey K.), чтобы сделать желаемый вывод с вопроса